# String similarity algorithms

Tags: algorithm, string-comparison, levenshtein-distance

I am comparing products across multiple stores. I only have access to the product name - which often differs between stores. For example: Store 1 might list a product as "iPhone 14 Midnight 128GB" whereas Store 2 lists it as "Apple iPhone 14 (128GB) - Midnight - NEW".

Typical string comparisons such as Levenshtein distance don't work particularly well for this task. I've had the most success with separating words, removing special characters, then calculating the Levenshtein distance for each word individually.

Is there an algorithm/library that would work well for this task?

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, you can use [trigram fuzzy search](https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/169-Fuzzy-string-matching-with-Trigram-and-Trigraphs.html) algorithm. Idea of this algorithm: split string to intersected trigrams, and compute maximal intersection score.

~20 years ago [John Wilbur](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/staff/wilbur/) designed, and I I wrote implementation of this algorithm, you can download my implementation of this [Wilbur-Khovayko](http://olegh.ftp.sh/wilbur-khovayko.tar.gz) algorithm.

This implementation search "N closest terms" for entered search term.

List of terms - in the file termlist.txt N - in the variable lim, file findtest.c

Algorithm is very quick: on the old Sun 200mHz, it search 100 closest term among 100,000 entries for ~0.3 secs.